# Responsibility of the http server vs responsibility of the web app hosted using this server

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I'm evaluating various hosting options for ASP.NET Core application.
In the new programming model of ASP.NET you process a request with a set of middlewares (which are mixture of older `IHttpModule` & `IHttpHandler`).

You can have a middleware which can be responsible for authentication, handling of static files or compressing the response before sending (just to name some).
Here comes the confusion.

**Where to set a border between server and an app in context of responsibility?**

Which side should be responsible for **compressing** the response? With IIS this was handled by the server and configured in web.config. Kestrel doesn't provide this functionality AFAIK, so you need to implement a custom middleware in the app which will handle this for you. Which one is more appropriate?

What about **authentication**? IIS provides settings for authentication (anonymous, impersonation, forms auth). On the opposite, in ASP.NET Core we can also write an app middleware which can handle this for us.

Ok, **SSL** is handled by server, because it's below in the protocol layer and app operates on HTTP(S) only.

What responsibilities should server have? What responsibilities should an app have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The server is responsible for implementing the base HTTP protocol, managing connections, etc.. It may also choose to offer other features (e.g. windows auth), but we recommend against it unless it can provide a distinct advantage over a middleware implementation. E.g. Windows auth could be implemented in middleware, but it would be much more difficult due to some of the connection management constraints. Compression could be implemented in middleware just as easily as in the server.

Comment: Who is we ("we recommend") ? Thanks for sharing your opinion.

Comment: asp.net-core team :-) https://github.com/orgs/aspnet/people?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=role%3Amember+tratcher

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_server):

> "The primary function of a web server is to store, process and deliver
>   web pages to clients"

The thing is that all famous http servers (nginx, apache, IIS, ...) come with a lot of modules that can handle lots of different tasks including the ones you mentioned in your question (authentication, compression, ...).

It's quite likely that the more modules you'll add the slowest your http server will be. IIS for instance is, by far, not known to be the fastest http server around, but if you remove all the modules and use it just for serving resources, then it will become really fast because this what it has been built for back in the days!

The problem of responsibility goes the same with all kind of software application.
Think about databases whose main role is to store data. RDBMS like Oracle or SQL Server are pretty good at it. But as soon as they release a new version, they also release a new functionality that has nothing to do with storing data. And people use it! ;-)
How many times people used their DB as a search engine? I saw people sending mails with SQL Server! But the worse was some guys trying to call webservices within store procedures ;-)

It's always tempting to have one tool to do everything but you need to keep in mind that it has not been built for every purpose. I'd rather use a bunch of lightweight tools that have one single responsibility and that handle it correctly instead.

Now back to your question, I think it's a good approach to make use of middlewares. That way you have control on the entire pipeline and you know exactly what your request have been through. Middlewares are also testable! Getting rid of all the unnecessary modules will definitely lead you to a more lightweight http server.

The righteous "it depends" answer is also acceptable. If you make some tests and realize that gzip compression module is 10x faster than the middleware, go with the module! Don't be dogmatic neither!